# Getting error in if statement

Tags: java

I am just trying to sort the string in descending order.  input provided by the user is 10,a,1,#,15,.,6 output must be 10,a,15,#,6,.,1 I have tried.

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string:");
String[] num = input.split(",");
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

 System.out.println(num);
  for ( int i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i ++ )  
   {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < num.length; j ++ )
     {
       if(Integer.parseInt(num[i]) 
       && Integer.parseInt(num[j])  
        && num[i] < num[j])  {
          String temp = num[ i ];   //swapping
           num[ i ] = num[ j ];
           num[ j ] = temp;
            }
            }           
      } 
     }
```

In if statement i get error. error:- The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) int, int
    - The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, 
     java.lang.String

Comment: Indeed.. `&&` is undefined for the argument type `int`.

Comment: I tried || even it is not working.

Comment: Because `||` is undefined for the argument type `int` as well. Your code is asking for something like: `if(5 && 6)` which make no sense in Java.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(num[i]) && Integer.parseInt(num[j])` seems meaning less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to make your code compile: recall that `Integer.parse` returns the integer, so you cannot use it in the sequence of logical expressions.

Then, you should make your code more efficient: move parsing of `num[i]` outside the loop, and skip the loop when parsing fails, like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i ++ ) {
    int numI;
    try { numI = Integer.parse(num[i]); } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { continue; }
    for (int j = i + 1; j < num.length; j ++ ) 
        int numJ;
        try { numJ = Integer.parse(num[i]); } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { continue; }
        if (numI < numJ) {
            String temp = num[ i ];   //swapping
            num[ i ] = num[ j ];
            num[ j ] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when parsing `num[i]` fails, the program skips over the nested loop, going to the next string instead.

Comment: i want to add num to arraylist arr.

Comment: @koshishkharel Make an `ArrayList<Integer> arr` instead of `ArrayList<String>`, use *one* loop to parse and add numbers to `arr`, and then use two loops to sort the results the way you did.

Comment: I am getting error in try catch block it says " The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer>".

Comment: @koshishkharel You cannot use `[]` operator with lists. Replace `num[x]` with `num.get(x)` when you read the value, and `num[x] =...` with `num.set(x, ...)` when you set the value to a position that already exists. If an element does not exist yet, use `num.add(...)` and pass the appropriate value.

Comment: what should i do while swapping?

Comment: @koshishkharel The same thing that you do with an array: `String temp = num.get(i); num.put(i, num.get(j)); num.put(j, temp);`

Answer (score 2):

You can replace

```
   if(Integer.parseInt(num[i]) 
      && Integer.parseInt(num[j])  
      && num[i] < num[j])  {
```

with

```
   if(Integer.parseInt(num[i])  <
      Integer.parseInt(num[j])) {
```

However, you'll get a NumberFormatException if one of the Strings can't be parsed as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your if from:

```
Integer.parseInt(num[i]) 
   && Integer.parseInt(num[j])  
    && num[i] < num[j]
```

To:

```
Integer.parseInt(num[i]) 
   < Integer.parseInt(num[j])  
   ^^^
    && num[i].compareTo(num[j]) < 0
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

If you want to compare two numbers, you could compare for less than/greater than and/or equal to. You could apply && on two booleans like `condition1 && condition2`

Aside note, if any of the number is not parseable as integer then you might get NumberFormatException. So i would suggest you first recognize input and then use the api to convert it to a number.

Comment: when do i add it to array? and in case of string input what should i do?

Comment: You could check if the element you have is either number or String by using `string.matches("^\\d+$")` if it returns true then that means its a number else its a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to look at the rest of your code, but the bit with the error should give an error. Here is an illustration:

```
Integer.parseInt(num[i]) --> an int
Integer.parseInt(num[j]) --> another int
```

`&&` takes two `boolean`s and gives a `boolean`, `true` if both evaluate to `true`.

However, two `int`s are given. What do we do with those?
That's right, an error.

```
num[i] --> a String object (remember the declaration: String[] num = ...)
num[j] --> another String object
```

`<` is the 'less than' comparison operator, which works on `int`s, `long`s, `short`s, `byte`s, `float`s and `double`s.

As `String` is not one of those numeric types, however, an error is thrown.

I think that you want to say `Integer.parseInt(num[i]) < Integer.parseInt(num[j])`. This works, because you give the `<` operator two `int`s. Some `int`s are greater than others, not the case with `String`s, so it compiles fine. But note the warning in Eran's answer; you will get a `NumberFormatException` if `Integer.parseInt()` is given an invalid input. To handle this, use a `try`/`catch`:

```
int numI, numJ;
try {
    numI = Integer.parseInt(num[i]);
    numJ = Integer.parseInt(num[j]);
    // rest of code
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // not a number, handle here!
}
```